# Display lists in a table form

Tags: plotting, functions, list-manipulation

I would like to display the lists in a table as in the image. 
How can I make it work?

```
list1 = {1/x, -1 + x, -(x/(-2 + x)), -1 + 1/x, -1 + 2 x};
list2 = {{{a, b}}, {{c, d}}, {{a, c}, {b, d}}, {{e, f}, {g, h}}, {{k, 
     t}}};
Grid[{list1, list2}, Frame -> All]
```

**UPDATE:** 
I would like to add some more information. `list1` and `list2` are data from some other processing so I have it in advance. 
The obove lists are just for example. The real lists are much longer and it would be nice to have able to do it automatically.
`list1` and `list2` have the same size. The length can be change and each element in `list2` may have one, two or more many sublists.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered formatting it into a `Dataset`?

Comment: @CATrevillian I didn't know that it exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lot's of ways to achieve this.  A few follow:

```
list1 = {"list1", 1/x, -1 + x, -(x/(-2 + x)), -1 + 1/x, -1 + 2 x};
list2 = {"list2", {{a, b}}, {{c, d}}, {{a, c}, {b, d}}, {{e, f}, {g, h}}, {{k, t}}};
list3 = {"No.", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

Grid[Transpose[{list3, list2, list1}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

This gets a bit closer:

```
list1 = {"list1", 1/x, -1 + x, -(x/(-2 + x)), "", -1 + 1/x, 
   "", -1 + 2 x};
list2a = {"", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
list2 = {"list2", {a, b}, {c, d}, {a, c}, {b, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}, {k, 
    t}};
list3 = {"No.", 1, 2, 3, SpanFromAbove, 4, SpanFromAbove, 5};

Grid[Transpose[{list3, list2a, list2, list1}], Frame -> All, 
 Spacings -> 2]
```

[image]

Even more close to your drawing:

```
Grid[Transpose[{list3, list2a, list2, list1}],
 Spacings -> 2,
 Dividers -> {
   {1 -> True, 2 -> True, 4 -> True, 5 -> True} (*Vertical*),
   {1 -> True, 2 -> True, 3 -> True, 4 -> True, 6 -> True, 8 -> True, 
    9 -> True}(*Horizontal*)
   }]
```

[image]

Your approach will depend on "all" of what you want to do, e.g.:

- A one-off table?
- An interface (maybe using `Manipulate`) to generate
  such displays dynamically?

In response to the OPs update of the question:

```
list1 = {1/x, -1 + x, -(x/(-2 + x)), -1 + 1/x, -1 + 2 x};
list2 = {{{a, b}}, {{c, d}}, {{a, c}, {b, d}}, {{e, f}, {g, h}}, {{k, 
     t}}};

list2elementCount = Range[Length[Flatten[list2, 1]]];
elementCounts = Length[#] & /@ list2;
list2elementNumbers = 
  Column[#] & /@ TakeList[list2elementCount, elementCounts];
list2Column = Column[#] & /@ list2;

Grid[Prepend[
  Transpose[{mainRows, list2elementNumbers, list2Column, 
    list1}], {"No.", "", "list2", "list1"}],
 Spacings -> {1, 1},
 Alignment -> {Center, Top},
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

The should work in all contexts presented by the OP.

Comment: This is nice but you kind of manually set `Dividers` and `list3` part. In my case, the number of elements are much bigger and this would take long time.

Comment: @anhnha -- I recommend that you add to your question.  Make the question more specific. If you can articulate the conditions, under which you want your "list 2" elements grouped, one can readily introduce them as conditionals in setting `Dividers`.  A description or explanation of what you need to do and its context will help you get better answers.  Otherwise everyone helping has to try and read your mind/intention.

Comment: As example what do the values in the two lists represent?  Additionally, do you structure the data or do you get it from somewhere?  What you do with the structure of the data (e.g., the hierarchy of lists) and when in your process, will do much to simplify or complicate the solution.  Also, at lease in the example given, one can fix the vertical dividers, the top row dividers, and the top, bottom, and left and right side dividers.  As such, introducing conditional formatting should not take too much work. It seems like you only need to do so for the horizontal dividers.

Comment: You're right. Your answer is pretty good for the given question. I'll add some more details so there may be some modifications to make it work for a large data.

Comment: What would be `mainRows`? I was able to do it but much longer than your code. 
Would it be possible to display the numbers and expressions in the center of cells? It is not essential though. Just wonder if it can be for a better looking.

Comment: This is mine. I change list names. 
https://codeshare.io/5QKNvL

Comment: @anhnha -- You can just change `Alignment -> {Center, Top}` to `Alignment -> Center` for the alignment you want to try.  I recommend you review `Grid` in the Wolfram Documentation, it will give you lots of ideas for formatting.  Also, feel free to post your answer to your question.  Great way to receive comments.

Comment: This is just additional question not for the original one. Is it possible to add a new column that is editable from that code?

Comment: @anhnha -- Certainly, but likely best to just ask as second question.

Answer (score 0):

My code is long and sometimes redundant. I'd like post it here to learn how to fix that.

```
list1a = {1/x, -1 + x, -(x/(-2 + x)), "", -1 + 1/x, "", -1 + 2 x};
list1b = Join[{ Style["list1", 16, Bold]}, list1a]
(* tuples*)
list2a = {{{a, b}}, {{c, d}}, {{a, c}, {b, d}}, {{e, f}, {g, h}}, {{d,
      t}}};
list2b = Join[{Style["list2", 16, Bold]}, Flatten[list2a, 1]];
(*span for col1*)
span = Length[#] & /@ list2a;
tupNum = {Style["Tup No.", 16, Bold], Sequence @@ Range[Plus @@ span]};
(*replace span position with -1*)
spanList = Flatten[If[# > 1, ConstantArray[-1, # - 1], 0] & /@ span]
spanPos = Position[spanList, _?(# != 0 &)] + 1;
spancol1 = 
 Join[{Style["Set No.", 16, Bold]}, 
  Insert[Range[Length[list2a]], SpanFromAbove, spanPos]]
(*horizontal dividers*)
horizDiv = 
  Thread[Join[{1, 2}, Accumulate[Length[#] & /@ list2a] + 2] -> 
    ConstantArray[True, Length[list2a] + 2]];
Grid[Transpose[{spancol1, tupNum, list2b, list1b}], Spacings -> 2, 
 Dividers -> {{1 -> True, 2 -> True, 3 -> True, 4 -> True, 
    5 -> True} (*Vertical*), horizDiv(*Horizontal*)}, 
 Background -> {{1 -> GrayLevel[.95], 2 -> LightBlue, 3 -> LightGreen,
     4 -> LightOrange}, None}]
```

[image]